# Nan values when plotting Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Hi i am trying to display a large merged data set into a scatter plot graph to find the relationship between The gdp per capita and number of kids. The dataframe looks someting like this. How do i remove the rows with Nan Values and plot the scatter? Or do i just plot the graph straight and it will ignore all rows with NaN value? Any help would be great thanks :) Also , when calculating the mean of the second and third column , do i show the result on another column?

```
Country | Number of kids | GDP per capita
  A     |      4         |    2345
  B     |      2         |    2156
  C     |     NaN        |    1156
  D     |     5          |    958
  E     |     NaN        |    NaN
  F     |     8          |    NaN
.
.
.
 Z      |     3          |    2
```

Comment: have you tried "plotting the graph straight"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pandas' `dropna()` function to remove nan and then plot it with a `scatter()` plot of matplotlib.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
enter code here
df = <your dataset>
plot_df = df.dropna()
plt.scatter(plot_df['Number of kids'], plot_df['GDP per capita'])
```

If your dataset is very large consider to use the sample function to randomly sample data:

```
df = df.sample(1000)
```